# HTML5 Tainted canvases may not be exported

Tags: javascript, html, createjs

I am trying to use CreateJS with spritesheet animations, and this has been a complete nightmare.

Every single time I try and use an image, I get complaints about Tainted Canvases. I've tried a public webserver, local file tag loading, and by using a local server from grunt. Currently, I am using grunt devserver (Which is designed entirely to be CORS open).

```
contentManager = new createjs.LoadQueue();
loadImages()
contentManager.on("complete", handleComplete, this);
```

It reports that the image is loaded perfectly fine, and so then I try to use it.

```
this.localSpriteSheet = new createjs.SpriteSheet({
        images: [contentManager.getResult(hero.imageName)], //image to use
        frames: hero.frames,
        animations: hero.animations
}),
```

This loads the image perfectly fine, and then I try to throw in some reversed frames.

```
createjs.SpriteSheetUtils.addFlippedFrames(this.localSpriteSheet, true, false, false),
```

And that is when it throws this stupid error no matter where the file is hosted.

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.
```

This is my code to load the image:

```
contentManager.loadManifest([{
    id: "warrior",
    src: "http://localhost:8888/img/warrior.png"
}]);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as this has been a complete nightmare to deal with.

Comment: Load the HTML page containing the canvas from the same domain as the images.

Comment: Not sure I get what you do. The *images*, if served from other domain, has to be CORS. Else they taint. One solution is using own server as proxy, another is looking for CORS proxy services. Depends on need usage etc.

Comment: Yes, you can use CORS on the server that serves the images. If you do this, you will have to set the crossOrigin flag on images used in the canvas. PreloadJS has support for this.